# CSS3 animation change background-image without sliding

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

This is the current code I have

```
.jack_hitting{
        -moz-animation: jackhitting 0.5s infinite;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes jackhitting {  
        0% {  
          background-position: -8px -108px;
        } 

        20% {  
          background-position: -41px -108px;
        }

        40% {  
          background-position: -73px -108px;
        }

        60% {  
          background-position: -105px -108px;
        }

        80% {  
          background-position: -137px -108px;
        }

        100% {  
          background-position: -8px -108px;
        }
    }
```

and this cycles through the background image sliding to the next one, but i would rather have it not slide, so that it basically works like the following js code:

```
document.getElementById('id').style.backgroundPosition='-8px -108px';
```

Is there an effect that can do what I would like?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not too savvy on the -moz-animation specifics, but based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/animation  it seems like you could get what you want with an animation-duration of 0 and an animation-delay of X seconds

Comment: no that doesn't work either :(, you had me hopeful there :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it: **step-start** (I think it's one of multiple that could do this in the **animation-timing-function** category)

```
animation: jackhitting 10s step-start infinite;
```

Long-form would be

```
animation-name: jackhitting;
animation-duration:    10s;
animation-timing-function: step-start;
animation-iteration-count:    infinite;
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to prefix this for each browser for now.

Here's a fiddle to test it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ym6b5/4/
(The div is much too big. I wanted you to see the background image move and see if it's what you were after)

The **animation-duration** is the total amount of time it'll take to go through your keyframes. The **animation-delay** that I thought was the delay between steps is the *delay before* the animation should start.
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-animations

Hope it's what you were looking for.
Cheers,
iso

Comment: Thanks, I#ll test it out, but the jsfiddle shows that it is possible

Comment: I had fun looking it up. Thanks for the opportunity. ;) Part of the fun of StackOverflow is researching stuff you'll end up using in two weeks.